# Method not found (Compact framework windows form implementing an interface)

Tags: c#, winforms, interface, compact-framework, windows-forms-designer

Windows Mobile 6.5 Application
VS 2008 (9.0.30729.4462)

I have a project `myproject.base` that has an interface `IGuiStuff`.

I have another project `myproject.impl` that has a control `ctrl` and a form `frm`.

`myproject.impl` references `myproject.base`.

The control `ctrl` implements `IGuiStuff`.

```
public interface IGuiStuff
{
    InputPanel MyPanel {get; set;}
}
```

When I use `ctrl` in `frm` i get an exception when trying to view the designer, saying that `MyPanel` isn't implemented by `ctrl`. However `MyPanel` **is** implemented by `ctrl`.

I have tried all kinds of clean/rebuild/delete stuff/references voodoo etc...

What should I try next?

**Update 1**

I have tried building a new project structure from scratch with the same settings as in the current projects. Then I have added all .cs, .Desiger.cs and .resx files from each project and built the project.
The exact same problem still occurs.

**Update 2**

Using ILSpy I can verify that the implementation is indeed complete.

I have also copied the project to a fresh installed computer, exactly the same error occurs.

**Update 3**

If I comment out the interface from the control definition I get another error trying to view the forms designer:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I also get an error for every user control stating that it was never assigned.

Btw, I have installed Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms, Version=3.5.0.0 into GAC.

**Update 4**

I've found the last version from source control before update to Compact Framework 3.5, it works. After 3.5 it doesn't. (It is only the designer, the final program works fine)

Is it a bug or is it something that goes wrong while upgrading?

Comment: without seeing the actual exception, could [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551677/inherited-winforms-usercontrols-unusable-after-modification) be of any help?

Comment: @MajorByte That is exactly the kind of problem I'm having. The error in my case is get_MyPanel isn't implemented.

Comment: I've had a lot of random troubles with the VS designer over the years... usually a recompile or something fixes it, I'm sorry that it's not working for you. One question jumps to mind: why would the designer care about a user-defined property (MyPanel) in a user-defined interface (IGuiStuff)?